# What does this stat mean in YouTube Stats for Nerds?

Tags: youtube, video-encoding

Under the field Current/Optimal Res, the resolution is followed by an '@' symbol followed by a number. I have tried to find out what this number represents but could not find any source. I am guessing its the average bit rate of a particular chunk of video? Is this correct?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCXee.png)

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's written as the screen resolution at a specific frame rate. I assume that means the video is running at 24fps.

Answer (score 1):

In "Current / Optimal Res", "Current" stands for viewport resolution
(playback area).
"Optimal res" stands for the best resolution user can have on that viewport.

An example output is :

```
Current / Optimal Res 1280x720@30 / 1280x720@30
```

Which means that both current and optimal resolutions are identical,
at width 1280 pixels, height 720 pixels, frequency 30 Hz.